# Safari does not send terminating WebSocket opcode

Tags: safari, websocket

I have a WebSocket server that works fine on all the major browsers including Safari... but for some reason on Safari for both OSX and iOS, when I close the browser window, or navigate to another page, etc I do not get any sort of closing opcode and the socket appears to stay open resulting in all my recv() calls to block and my send() calls to continue to succeed. This is resulting in loads of zombie threads consuming resources for users that are not actually active. Is there some other magic necessary for handling this in Safari?